# appendChild content doesn't stay even when if condition has been met

Tags: javascript, if-statement, appendchild

I'm using javascript to check required fields in a form, so that a field is styled and an error message appears if it's empty on `focusout`. (This is to supplement a Kirby CMS form plugin that validates on submit only.)

The behaviour I'm trying to create is...

- When a required field is left empty, styling and message appear on `focusout`.
- Styling and message remain visible until either (a) the field is in focus state again or (b) the field is populated.
- If a required field is 'refocussed', left blank and focus left again, the message and styling reappear.

My problem is that the input styling (red border-bottom) works as intended but the error message, which is based in the `appendChild` function, does not. The error message only appears one at a time with the last focussed required field and I can't figure out how to get the message to stay in place the same way the styling does.

Because, in practice, forms will be created by content-managers using the CMS, I want the script to be vanilla JS and as generic as possible, avoiding targeting specific IDs. Instead, I'm trying to do this based on the `required` attribute and the `querySelectorAll` function. I have some variables to specity the error message text and a `for` loop to target just the 'offending' fields that don't meet the criteria of an `if` statement.

```js
function reqdCheck() {
  const reqdFields = document.querySelectorAll("main input[required], main textarea[required]");
  const reqdPara = document.createElement("p");
  const reqdText = document.createTextNode("This field is required.");
  reqdPara.appendChild(reqdText);
  
  for (const reqdField of reqdFields) {
    reqdField.addEventListener ("focusout", function() {
        if (reqdField.value == "" || reqdField.value == null) {
        reqdField.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
        reqdField.style.boxShadow = "0 1px 0 0 red";
        reqdField.parentNode.appendChild(reqdPara);
      }
      else {
        reqdField.style.borderBottom = "1px solid black";
        reqdField.style.boxShadow = "none";
      }
    })
    reqdField.addEventListener ("focusin", function() {
      if (reqdField.value == "" || reqdField.value == null) {
        reqdField.style.borderBottom = "1px solid orange";
        reqdField.style.boxShadow = "0 1px 0 0 orange";
        reqdField.parentNode.removeChild(reqdPara);
      }
    })
  }
}
reqdCheck()
```

```css
input:not([type="submit"]),
textarea {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

input:not([type="submit"]):focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 orange;
}

.field-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.field-group p {
  color: red;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form id="a2a64e93-2b60-4ad9-9445-ce61f5852594" action="#">
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="fname">First name:*</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="John" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Doe">
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="company">Company:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="company" placeholder="Acme Ltd">
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="email">Email:*</label><br>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john@acme.com" required>
     </div>
    <div class="field-group">
      <label for="email">Message:*</label><br>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</main>
```

What am I missing to get the appendChild error message to stay visible as intended? Is there a more efficient way to achieve what I'm after? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that you are creating only one `p` element (the error text) and you want to append it multiple times. In order to resolve this, you should add all the `reqdPara` logics inside the for loop. Take a look here:

```
function reqdCheck() {
  const reqdFields = document.querySelectorAll(
    'main input[required], main textarea[required]'
  );

  for (const reqdField of reqdFields) {
    const reqdPara = document.createElement('p');
    const reqdText = document.createTextNode('This field is required.');

    reqdPara.appendChild(reqdText);

    reqdField.addEventListener('focusout', function () {
      if (reqdField.value === '' || reqdField.value === null) {
        reqdField.style.borderBottom = '1px solid red';
        reqdField.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 0 0 red';
        reqdField.parentNode.appendChild(reqdPara);
      } else {
        reqdField.style.borderBottom = '1px solid black';
        reqdField.style.boxShadow = 'none';
      }
    });
    reqdField.addEventListener('focusin', function () {
      if (reqdField.value == '' || reqdField.value == null) {
        reqdField.style.borderBottom = '1px solid orange';
        reqdField.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 0 0 orange';
        reqdField.parentNode.removeChild(reqdPara);
      }
    });
  }
}
reqdCheck();
```

Comment: Thanks, score30. That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/**
 * Reference <form>
 * Bind <form> to the "focusout" event 
 * Bind <form> to the "focusin" event
 */
const profile = document.forms.profile;
profile.addEventListener('focusout', requiredData);
profile.addEventListener('focusin', clearData);

// htmlString for error message
const req = `<output name="error">This field is required</output>`;

/**
 * Event handler passes (e)vent object by default
 * Reference the element being unfocused by user
 * If said element is NOT <form> AND said element has the 
 * attribute "required"...
 * ...and if said element is blank...
 * Insert error message after said element and add ".error"
 * class to it
 */
function requiredData(e) {
  const leaving = e.target;
  if (leaving != this && leaving.hasAttribute("required")) {
    if (leaving.value === "") {
/* Uncomment the next line and comment the line after the  next line if you prefer the error message inside the <label> */     //leaving.previousElementSibling.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", req);
      leaving.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", req)
      leaving.classList.add("error");
      return;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Pretty much the same as requiredData(e) except...
 * The third criteria looks for the ".error" class on the
 * element the user focused on.
 * The ".error" class and error message is removed
 */
function clearData(e) {
  const entering = e.target;
  if (entering !== this && entering.hasAttribute("required")) {
    if (entering.matches(".error")) {
      entering.classList.remove("error");
      /* Uncomment the next line and comment the line after the  next line if you prefer the error message inside the <label> */
      //entering.previousElementSibling.querySelector("[name='error']").remove();
      entering.nextElementSibling.remove();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 300 2ch/1.1 "Segoe UI"
}

.profile {
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
}

fieldset+fieldset {
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

label sup,
legend sup {
  color: red;
}

.fc {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.fc:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 orange;
}

label,
button,
input,
textarea {
  display: block;
  font: inherit;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem
}

label {
  width: max-content;
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
  white-space: pre;
}

legend+label {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

label,
input,
textarea {
  width: 99%;
}

#phone {
  width: 12ch;
}

button {
  float: right;
  width: max-content;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

output {
  border: 0;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.error {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: red;
  background: rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form id="a2a64e93-2b60-4ad9-9445-ce61f5852594" name="profile" action="#">
    <fieldset class="profile">
      <legend>Profile</legend>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Full Name</legend>
        <label for="fname">First:<sup>✱</sup></label>
        <input id="fname" name="fullname" class="fc" type="text" placeholder="John" required>

        <label for="lname">Last:<sup>✱</sup></label>
        <input id="lname" name="fullname" class="fc" type="text" placeholder="Doe" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Location</legend>
        <label for="company">Company:</label>
        <input id="company" name="location" class="fc" type="text" placeholder="Acme Ltd">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <textarea id="address" name="location" class="fc" placeholder="123 Main St.
Springfield, IL 62702" rows="3" cols="22"></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact</legend>
        <label for="email">Email:<sup>✱</sup></label>
        <input id="email" name="contact" class="fc" type="email" placeholder="john@acme.com" required>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input id="phone" name="contact" class="fc" type="tel" placeholder="123-456-7890" pattern="\(?\d{3}[)\- ]\d{3}[\- ]\d{4}">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Message:<sup>✱</sup></legend>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" class="fc" placeholder="Enter message here" required></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <Button>Submit</Button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</main>
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/d9mtjxkL/)

Comment: Thanks, zer00ne. That is also a great solution.